# Context in Express Request is not exist in runtime?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, guard

I extended the Express request object with a custom variable like the below:

```
import { Context } from 'common/interfaces';

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      context: Context;
    }
  }
}
```

and declaration of Context is like below:

```
import { DecodedIdToken } from 'firebase-admin/lib/auth/token-verifier';
import { User } from './user.interface';

export interface Context {
  clientId: string;
  firebaseUser: DecodedIdToken;
  user: User;
}
```

I added the custom types folder into the tsconfig.json file like below:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "src/@types",
  "node_modules/@types"
]
```

I am using this extended context variable in a NestJS guard.

```
const request: Request = executionContext.switchToHttp().getRequest();
request.context.firebaseUser = request.user as DecodedIdToken;
```

Typescript recognizes this variable. There is no problem with Typescript but in runtime, `context` does not exist in the request object. It returns `undefined`.

How can I introduce the `context` variable in the request object and use it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set `request.context`?

Comment: Explicitly, nowhere. Should I do that? I have already set it up in index.d.ts file. Is it not enough? @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0):

In the `d.ts` file `request.context` has been declared to be an object with a `firebaseUser` property, but that's only for Typescript's knowledge. You still need to make sure to set `request.context` to an object before trying to tack on more properties to it. Or assign `request.context =  { firebaseUser: request.user }` instead of `request.context.firebaseUser = request.user`